# Laravel Eloquent Aggregates (Max) return 500 server error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using this previously to get the MAX recordID from eloquent model. Unfortunately when the database table row more than 20k then it will return 500 internal server error.

I have checked laravel.log and also apache error log but couldn't get any clue..

After that I try to echo "XXX"; exit(); before each line of my code and found that the exit() stop run after this line.

```
$lastRecord_sync = \App\TableModel::all()->max('record_id');
```

Then I tried to change to below and it just working fine.

```
$lastRecord_sync = DB::table('tms_door_record_raw')->max('record_id');
```

May I know what is actually the issue here? Does the SQL different from Eloquent Model and DB Query builder?

Comment: The first line retrieves all records to your application and then applies the max. That is inefficient (as you noticed already)

Comment: Is php not timing out after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$lastRecord_sync = \App\TableModel::all()->max('record_id');
```

Is telling laravel to retrieve all records in the table as a collection, then get the max `record_id` in that collection (see: [Collections: max](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-max)), presumably by looping over the entire collection which can be extremely slow if you have many records.

The second snippet:

```
$lastRecord_sync = DB::table('tms_door_record_raw')->max('record_id');
```

Is telling laravel to essentally execute this query (see: [Query Builder: Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates)):

```
SELECT MAX('record_id') FROM table;
```

MySQL is much more efficient at finding the max record than PHP is looping through each record in the collection and finding the max `record_id` there.